Not sure why the method "name" is not available
I was trying to understand better how enums and standard methods work.
I compile the code with iverilog -g 2012  example.sv in Icarus Verilog version 11.0 (stable).
I get the error sorry: Enumeration method name() is not currently supported in this context (self-determined).
Code (example.sv):
package test;
  typedef enum {IDLE, LOAD} state_t;
endpackage

//-------------------------------

import test::state_t;
import test::IDLE;
module package_example;
  state_t s = IDLE;
  initial begin
    $display("%d", s.name());
    $finish;
  end
endmodule

Can someone explain to me what's happening or give me a good starting point to understand?

Using a newer version of iverilog on EDA Playground (12.0) produces a different error message:
vvp error: get 3 not supported by vpiConstant (String)
WARNING: testbench.sv:12: incompatible value for $display<%d>.
<%d>

This is arguably more helpful than the error you got.  Removing the %d decimal notation format eliminates the error and warning messages, and produces the expected output: IDLE
$display(s.name());

%d is used to format numeric values, but the name method returns a string type.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2023, section 6.19.5.6 Name()

A SystemVerilog string is not an "integral type" and cannot be used here. On EDA Playground Cadence throws an error, Questa prints a string (wrong), and VCS prints a number. Clearly an undefined behavior, with Xcelium having the strictest interpretation of the LRM.
Therefore, your print flag %d should be %s
